# Alert script is not working in ScriptManager for multiple RAISERROR message from stored procedure

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have written a stored procedure that returns error message using RAISERROR if certain conditions fails.Sometimes multiple conditions fails and multiple RAISERROR messages will come and in the code i want to alert these messages.For single message ScriptManager is working without any problem but for multiple RAISERROR it is not working and firebug in mozilla shows an error "unterminated string literal".How can i solve this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc1] @RequestId BIGINT

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  BEGIN TRAN

  IF @RequestId < 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('MESSAGE1',16,1)
    END

  SET @RequestId = @RequestId + 100

  IF @RequestId < 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('MESSAGE2',16,1)
    END

 UPDATE Table1 SET ID = @RequestId 

 SELECT @RequestId AS ID

  COMMIT TRAN
END
```

In vb code

```
        Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConStrMain").ConnectionString)
            con.Open()
            Using transaction As SqlTransaction = con.BeginTransaction
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("proc1", con, transaction)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestId", RequestId)
                    Try
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        transaction.Commit()
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(System.Web.UI.Page), "", "alert('Request Successfully Completed');", True)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        transaction.Rollback()
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(System.Web.UI.Page), "", "alert('"+ex.Message+"');", True)
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, but have you tried calling a client-side function for the alerts, instead of just using the `alert(...)` line? Try doing something like this: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "yourfunction", "yourFunction('"+ex.Message+"');", True)`. Of course, you'll have to define `yourFunction(ex)` in the JavaScript code. 
`

Comment: It's possible you are getting a different SQL error, which is not encoded correctly and causing a JS error because of that.  View the source of the page to determine what message is being rendered.  It may also be a server-side error in code and that is being caught and displayed to you.